# Perl Mechanize run into error: failed connecting to "localhost", port 4242: so what?

Tags: perl, parsing, mechanize, mozilla, host

[first of all; i run linux opensuse 11.4 ]

i try to run this little programme on a linux box.

Update: Hmmm well i guess that i have damned serious issues with the installation of
MECHA::FireFox Hmm - i should have to work through the steps in WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::Troubleshooting! But believe me - this is pretty damned hard to do: Especially the "Installation" section seems particularly applicable to my situation here!

There might some terrible things -happened. What should i do now!!?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();

open(INPUT, "urls.txt") or die "Can't open file: $!";

while (<INPUT>) {
  chomp;
  $mech->get($_);
  my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
}
close(INPUT);
exit;
```

prerequisites:

i have a collection of ursl - stored in urls.txt 
i have installed mechanize and  WWW::Mechanize::Firefox

If i run the script i get fatal errors -

linux-vi17:/home/martin/bin # perl get_shots.pl
Failed to connect to , problem connecting to "localhost", port 4242: 
connecting to the denied at  /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Client.pm line 144

but wait - i also have installed the mozlRepl ....

```
K
Running make test
/usr/bin/perl "-Iinc" Makefile.PL --config= --installdeps=Class::Accessor::Fast,0,Module::Pluggable::Fast,0,Template,0,Template::Provider::FromDATA,0,UNIVERSAL::require,0
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/00-load.t t/10-plugin-repl-enter.t t/11-plugin-repl-search.t t/12-plugin-repl-inspect.t t/13-plugin-repl-load.t t/14-plugin-repl-rename.t t/15-plugin-repl-print.t t/16-plugin-repl-home.t t/17-plugin-repl-back.t t/18-plugin-repl-util-help_url_for.t t/19-plugin-repl-util-doc_for.t t/20-plugin-json.t t/pod-coverage.t t/pod.t
t/00-load.t ........................... 1/3 # Testing MozRepl 0.06
t/00-load.t ........................... ok   
t/10-plugin-repl-enter.t .............. [DEBUG] MozRepl logging enabled
[DEBUG] 
---- Client arguments ----
.----------------------+------------------------------------------.
| client_arg_name      | client_arg_value                         |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| host                 | localhost                                |
| port                 | 4242                                     |
| timeout              | 10                                       |
| extra_client_args    | {}                                       |
'----------------------+------------------------------------------'
t/10-plugin-repl-enter.t .............. ok   
t/11-plugin-repl-search.t ............. [DEBUG] MozRepl logging enabled
[DEBUG] 
---- Client arguments ----
.----------------------+------------------------------------------.
| client_arg_name      | client_arg_value                         |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| host                 | localhost                                |
| port                 | 4242                                     |
| timeout              | 10                                       |
| extra_client_args    | {}                                       |
'----------------------+------------------------------------------'
t/11-plugin-repl-search.t ............. ok   
t/12-plugin-repl-inspect.t ............ [DEBUG] MozRepl logging enabled
[DEBUG] 
---- Client arguments ----
.----------------------+------------------------------------------.
| client_arg_name      | client_arg_value                         |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| host                 | localhost                                |
| port                 | 4242                                     |
| timeout              | 10                                       |
| extra_client_args    | {}                                       |
'----------------------+------------------------------------------'
t/12-plugin-repl-inspect.t ............ ok   
t/13-plugin-repl-load.t ............... [DEBUG] MozRepl logging enabled
[DEBUG] 
---- Client arguments ----
.----------------------+------------------------------------------.
| client_arg_name      | client_arg_value                         |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| host                 | localhost                                |
| port                 | 4242                                     |
| timeout              | 10                                       |
| extra_client_args    | {}                                       |
'----------------------+------------------------------------------'
t/13-plugin-repl-load.t ............... ok   
t/14-plugin-repl-rename.t ............. [DEBUG] MozRepl logging enabled
[DEBUG] 
---- Client arguments ----
.----------------------+------------------------------------------.
| client_arg_name      | client_arg_value                         |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| host                 | localhost                                |
| port                 | 4242                                     |
| timeout              | 10                                       |
| extra_client_args    | {}                                       |
'----------------------+------------------------------------------'
t/14-plugin-repl-rename.t ............. ok   
t/15-plugin-repl-print.t .............. [DEBUG] MozRepl logging enabled
[DEBUG] 
---- Client arguments ----
.----------------------+------------------------------------------.
| client_arg_name      | client_arg_value                         |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| host                 | localhost                                |
| port                 | 4242                                     |
| timeout              | 10                                       |
| extra_client_args    | {}                                       |
'----------------------+------------------------------------------'
t/15-plugin-repl-print.t .............. ok   
t/16-plugin-repl-home.t ............... [DEBUG] MozRepl logging enabled
[DEBUG] 
---- Client arguments ----
.----------------------+------------------------------------------.
| client_arg_name      | client_arg_value                         |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| host                 | localhost                                |
| port                 | 4242                                     |
| timeout              | 10                                       |
| extra_client_args    | {}                                       |
'----------------------+------------------------------------------'
t/16-plugin-repl-home.t ............... ok   
t/17-plugin-repl-back.t ............... [DEBUG] MozRepl logging enabled
[DEBUG] 
---- Client arguments ----
.----------------------+------------------------------------------.
| client_arg_name      | client_arg_value                         |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| host                 | localhost                                |
| port                 | 4242                                     |
| timeout              | 10                                       |
| extra_client_args    | {}                                       |
'----------------------+------------------------------------------'
t/17-plugin-repl-back.t ............... ok   
t/18-plugin-repl-util-help_url_for.t .. [DEBUG] MozRepl logging enabled
[DEBUG] 
---- Client arguments ----
.----------------------+------------------------------------------.
| client_arg_name      | client_arg_value                         |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| host                 | localhost                                |
| port                 | 4242                                     |
| timeout              | 10                                       |
| extra_client_args    | {}                                       |
'----------------------+------------------------------------------'
t/18-plugin-repl-util-help_url_for.t .. ok   
t/19-plugin-repl-util-doc_for.t ....... [DEBUG] MozRepl logging enabled
[DEBUG] 
---- Client arguments ----
.----------------------+------------------------------------------.
| client_arg_name      | client_arg_value                         |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| host                 | localhost                                |
| port                 | 4242                                     |
| timeout              | 10                                       |
| extra_client_args    | {}                                       |
'----------------------+------------------------------------------'
t/19-plugin-repl-util-doc_for.t ....... ok   
t/20-plugin-json.t .................... [DEBUG] MozRepl logging enabled
[DEBUG] 
---- Client arguments ----
.----------------------+------------------------------------------.
| client_arg_name      | client_arg_value                         |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| host                 | localhost                                |
| port                 | 4242                                     |
| timeout              | 10                                       |
| extra_client_args    | {}                                       |
'----------------------+------------------------------------------'
t/20-plugin-json.t .................... ok   
t/pod-coverage.t ...................... skipped: Test::Pod::Coverage 1.04 required for testing POD coverage
t/pod.t ............................... skipped: Test::Pod 1.14 required for testing POD
All tests successful.
Files=14, Tests=42,  7 wallclock secs ( 0.14 usr  0.08 sys +  2.98 cusr  0.36 csys =  3.56 CPU)
Result: PASS
  ZIGOROU/MozRepl-0.06.tar.gz
  make test -- OK
Running make install
/usr/bin/perl "-Iinc" Makefile.PL --config= --installdeps=Class::Accessor::Fast,0,Module::Pluggable::Fast,0,Template,0,Template::Provider::FromDATA,0,UNIVERSAL::require,0
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Log.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Client.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Util.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/Base.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/JSON.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/Repl/Search.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/Repl/Load.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/Repl/Rename.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/Repl/Inspect.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/Repl/Home.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/Repl/Enter.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/Repl/Print.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/Repl/Back.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/Repl/Util/DocFor.pm
Installing /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/MozRepl/Plugin/Repl/Util/HelpUrlFor.pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::Repl::Util::DocFor.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::Repl::Print.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::Repl::Inspect.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::Repl::Back.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::Repl::Rename.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::Repl::Util::HelpUrlFor.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Client.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::JSON.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::Base.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Log.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::Repl::Load.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Util.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::Repl::Home.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::Repl::Search.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl::Plugin::Repl::Enter.3pm
Installing /usr/share/man/man3/MozRepl.3pm
Appending installation info to /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
  ZIGOROU/MozRepl-0.06.tar.gz
  make install  -- OK
```

**Update:** Hmmm well i guess that i have damned serious issues with the installation of
MECHA::FireFox Hmm - i should have to work through the steps in WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::Troubleshooting! But believe me - this is pretty damned hard to do: Especially the "Installation" section seems particularly applicable to my situation here!

plz let me know what goes wrong here... !? Do not let me out in the dark

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It's clear, useful and shows research effort

Comment: Hello Zaid - thx for the answer  - well i am a bit clueless. How to proceed?! What do you suggest!?

Comment: **Update:** again me - dear Zaid: Hmmm well i guess that i have damned serious issues with the installation of MECHA::FireFox Hmm - i should have to work through the steps in WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::Troubleshooting! But believe me - this is pretty damned hard to do: Especially the "Installation" section seems particularly applicable to my situation here!

Comment: I didn't answer your question. Quentin did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you haven't turned mozlRepl on. It doesn't listen all the time.

Comment: many many thanks for the reply - well i am a bit clueless. How to proceed?! What do you suggest!?

Comment: **Update:** Hmmm well i guess that i have damned serious issues with the installation of
MECHA::FireFox Hmm - i should have to work through the steps in WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::Troubleshooting! But believe me - this is pretty damned hard to do: Especially the "Installation" section seems particularly applicable to my situation here!

Comment: Turn it on. Tools > MozRepl > Start.